# max in one column and min in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

For example, if Column A and Column B have values:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 
| 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

From each group of B, I want to get the highest number from A. However, I don't want to include results where the number in B is higher, yet has a smaller A value than the previous one. I know this doesn't make sense in words, but this is what I want the final result to look like:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 |
+---+---+
```

So far I have something like "select max(a), b from table1 group by b" but this doesn't omit the ones where B is higher but the max A is smaller. I know that I could just peruse the results of that query in PHP and remove the ones where the A value is smaller than the previous A value, but I want to put it all in the mysql query if possible.

Comment: Could you explain why there is no value for b=2 in your output?  I can't follow the logic as you explain it.

Comment: Are the group values in B contiguous?

Comment: When grouped by B, the max value of A that has a value of 2 for B is 5. Since the max for A for the 1 group is 6, I don't want to include the 5 found from the 2 group. Then when we look at the 3 group, the max is 7, which is higher than the first one I found, so I want to include the 7 from the 3 group. In the 4 group, the max is 5, which is lower than any numbers from A that I have included, so I exclude the 4 group.

Comment: No, the B values are not continuous. I just happened to write my sample data like that.

Comment: Suppose the next row has "A"=6 and "B"=10. What is the expected result?

Comment: So Andy is asking whether you really mean that you ignore results where A is smaller than the "previous one"? Or do you also ignore results where A is smaller than "any of the previous ones"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to use a variable to store the value of `a` from the previous row and make the comparison on each iteration. This also accounts for the case where you might have gaps in the `b` column, where numbers aren't exactly in perfect sequential order:

```
SELECT @val:=a.a AS a, a.b
FROM
(
  SELECT MAX(a) AS a, b
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY b
) a
WHERE a.a > IFNULL(@val,-1)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic technique. Rationale for my edit: On my version of MySQL (5.5.25a), starting with an un-initialized @val will not work, and I added a sort on B in the subquery since I can only hope the original asker is not trusting the order of the rows in their DB.

Comment: I reflected a little, and realized we can convert a NULL `@val` to 0 in the comparison, eliminating the need to initialize `@val`.

Comment: @ctrahey, IIRC, `GROUP BY` also acts as an implicit `ORDER BY` in ascending order.

Comment: Today you have taught me two things :-) Thanks! -- "If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns." -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: @ctrahey, thanks for the `IFNULL()` edit. When I tested it, the uninitialized variable wasn't a problem, but it is best to be safe using `IFNULL`. I also made it a `-1` assuming the lowest number in the table is `0`.

Comment: Thank you! this is easy for me to understand and it worked perfectly. I also learned quite a few things from y'all.

Answer (score 5):

This technique joins the table against the aggregated version of itself, but the join is **offset by one**, so that every row is joined to the knowledge of the previous-B's MAX(A) value. It then matches rows where the current A is greater than any of those, and if it doesn't find any, it doesn't include the row. We then aggregate the final selection to get the results you are after.

```
SELECT 
       MAX(source_row.A) as A, 
       source_row.B
  FROM ab as source_row
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(A) as A, B FROM ab GROUP BY B) AS one_back 
    ON one_back.B = source_row.B-1 
 WHERE (one_back.A IS NULL) 
    OR one_back.A < source_row.A
 GROUP BY B
```

I have tested this :-)

## edit: extra insight

I wanted to share a little insight into how I come up with these kind of solutions; 'cause I think it's important for folks to start to "think in sets"... that's the best advice I ever read regarding JOINS, that you need to envision the intermediate "sets" that your query was working with. To illustrate this, here is a representation of the intermediate "set" that is the critical part of this query; it is the table as it exists "joined" to the aggregated version of itself off-by-one.

```
+------+------+------------+------------+
| A    | B    | one_back.B | one_back.A |
+------+------+------------+------------+
|    2 |    1 |       NULL |       NULL |
|    5 |    1 |       NULL |       NULL |
|    6 |    1 |       NULL |       NULL |
|    1 |    2 |          1 |          6 |
|    5 |    2 |          1 |          6 |
|    0 |    2 |          1 |          6 |
|    2 |    3 |          2 |          5 |
|    7 |    3 |          2 |          5 |
|    4 |    3 |          2 |          5 |
|    5 |    4 |          3 |          7 |
+------+------+------------+------------+
```

And then the set as it *actually* is created in-memory (the full join'd version is never fully in memory, since MySQL can eliminate rows as soon as it knows they are not going to "make the cut":

```
+------+------+------------+------------+
| A    | B    | one_back.B | one_back.A |
+------+------+------------+------------+
|    2 |    1 |       NULL |       NULL |
|    5 |    1 |       NULL |       NULL |
|    6 |    1 |       NULL |       NULL |
|    7 |    3 |          2 |          5 |
+------+------+------------+------------+
```

And then, of course, it aggregates the results from there into the final form, selecting only the A and B from the original rows.

Comment: +1 Neat solution. The only thing is that it *assumes* there will be no gap in the aggregated b column (like 1,2,4,5)

Comment: I love the elaboration. Nice job!

Comment: You are correct. If there is a gap, the rows with B = (gap+1) will have their place in the result set even if the condition of (gap-1) may have made it otherwise. So if that's part of the spec, this solution would need to be tweaked (and that may be understating what would need to happen :-)

Comment: @andyholaday thanks; I'm a fan of passing on the "bug" of actually *enjoying* thinking in SQL :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Z.a, Z.b from
(select a, b, rank() over (order by b) as ranker from (select max(a) a, b  from table1 group by b) Y) Z left join
(select a, b, rank() over (order by b) as ranker from (select max(a) a, b  from table1 group by b) Y1) Z1
on Z.ranker = Z1.ranker + 1
where Z.a > isnull(Z1.a, -100000)
```

Comment: This is MySQL, which doesn't support `rank()`